# Multiple bootstrap carousels don't go simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a static html page, with a big table.
In every row there are two bootstrap carousels and they work good.
But after few minutes each carousel doesn't go simultaneously.
They start on page loading, and they have the same time interval.

[carousels problem gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKm0b.gif)

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
      <div id="myCarousel1-1" class="carousel slide">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="img/lufthansa.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/swiss.png"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div id="myCarousel1-2" class="carousel slide vertical">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">AT800</div>
            <div class="item">FR90090</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <div id="myCarousel2-1" class="carousel slide vertical">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="img/swiss.png"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/swiss.png"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div id="myCarousel2-2" class="carousel slide vertical">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">FR90090</div>
            <div class="item">FR90090</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
   $('.carousel').carousel({
       interval: 3000,
       ride: true,
       pause: false,
       keyboard: false
   });
</script>
```

I would like every carousel go at the same time, simultaneously.

Comment: JavaScript is, by nature single threaded, eventually anything like this will be out of sync due to that.  You will have to "resync" them with some manual script but it will still always be off a bit - resync may just be a page refresh...